# draw a line on c++ using qtcreator

Tags: c++, graphics, qt-creator

I am extremely new on both c++ and qtcreator. At school I asked for draw a line between 2 crossed corner of an image. I am planning to use the Bresenhams Algorithm to calculate the line however I don`t know anything about the graphics library.

Can you tell me how to put a dot to a point which calculated by the algorithm?

Comment: QT is an abstraction layer, I doubt it would require you to use Bresenham by yourself just for drawing a line.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague. qtcreator is just a GUI for QT development, there is [graphic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-graphics.html) library in QT that should be used for your purposes, but anyway, you should gain some level in c++/qt (i.e. not to be an "extremely new") to successfully utilize it.